# Would I be better off with an oversized air conditioner or augmenting with a window unit on a 60A service?

Tags: wiring, cooling

I have 60 amp service coming into my house. I'm looking at installing a through the wall air conditioner. The ceilings are 10 foot so I know that I'm going to need to oversize the standard BTU rating. I looked up what I should multiply the square footage by for a 10 foot ceiling and it is 35. So the math is 500*35. Which leaves me with 17,500 BTU.

Local stores only stock 23,500 BTU units. They are double the price of the 12,500 BTU units but only pull 2 more amps. Since I need to cut a hole in my brick wall for this AC unit I want to make sure that it's properly sized.

I was thinking that if I undersize it and I need to put a through window air conditioner in my bedroom that my amperage being pulled would double instead of just going up 2 amps with the bigger unit. I'm not sure if I should splurge On a 23,500 BTU unit or Just run the risk over overloading my circuit if I need to put a through window ac in my room to supplement the smaller 12,500 unit.

Comment: Don't believe anything they say about square footage and BTU rating. The #1 thing that matters for BTUs is how much direct sun your walls get.  The sun blasting your walls and roof **is the primary source of heat gain**. Square footage has nothing to do with this. Solar gain (raw) is about 300 BTU/hr per square foot - though insulation slows this down a lot.   In other words, fudge those "square foot" BTU numbers significantly up or down depending on how exposed or shaded the place is.

Answer (score 5):

Given the constraint here, i.e. that you have to cut a hole in a brick wall, I would focus on getting the right unit instead of going with what is easily locally available. Slide-in units are available in many different sizes, so if your local stores don't stock the size you need, you should probably order one in, either via a local dealer or through an online seller.

To determine the correct size, the best method is a [Manual J](https://www.load-calculations.com/what-is-acca-manual-j-.html) calculation to determine the real heating or cooling load needed. If you can't do a Manual J, it makes sense to apply a rule-of-thumb like you're doing, but I would caution against oversizing. Oversizing can lead to poor comfort, particularly for cooling. [See this blog post for some explanation](https://www.pvhvac.com/blog/what-are-sensible-and-latent-heat-and-why-do-they-matter-for-hvac). If you have to get it wrong, my opinion is get it wrong in the too small direction. A slightly warmer but dehumidified room is often far more comfortable than a cooler room which feels clammy.

Also, if you are seeing double the cooling for a small bump in power, look carefully at the efficiency of the units you're considering. The efficiency is [measured in SEER](https://www.wfsmith.com/blog/understanding-seer-ratings/), and higher is better up to a point. You're going to live with this for years, so it's worth making certain you install an efficient unit.

Comment: Every word of this answer.  Plus, relying on a through-wall unit to heat multiple rooms isn't ideal.  Start off with a plan for a unit in the bedroom too.  Find two units that come as close as possible to what you need without requiring an electrical service upgrade.  Consider keeping the bedroom door closed, not cooling it during the day, and only cooling it at night.  Consider either an electrical service upgrade or converting other large electrics (dryer, range) to gas.

Comment: Nice. Now go clean up your redundant comment(s). :)

Comment: Pretty sure someone else already did.

Answer (score 1):

A half-ton (6,000 btu) oversize isn't a bad idea assuming you have enough air flowing to the entire living space or else it will cool the immediate vicinity and shut off; aka short-cycling.

2 amps for double the BTU is hard to ignore.

A big secret to A/C is that it works by dehumidifying the space so it needs to be able to run for an ample amount of time to first dehumidify and then you will feel the cooling. Short-cycling increases the chances for things to break, fyi.

Comment: Well, short-cycling is only an issue if the unit starts up too soon after it shut down, before refrigerant pressures have been able to equalize in the system.  The compressor has to start against high pressure, which it's not sized to do.

Answer (score 1):

### Think about a mini-split instead.

Mini-splits are excellent for you because only need a small hole through the brick wall, instead of a wall A/C sized units. The interior footprint is no bigger *and they are much quieter*.  If you were hemming and hawing about mini-splits, *please* learn some more and consider them seriously.

Yes, it confuses the matter of "how to heat", but simply: heat pumps when they're efficient (which is 95% of the time these days) otherwise run your existing heat as an "emergency heat".

An air conditioner is already a heat pump, but it can't pump both ways because it's missing a $12 reversing valve and some software. They get exploitive prices only because of low production and high demand.

Aside from needing a small hole, mini-splits also tend to be a) far more efficient, saving money; and b) reversible to pump the heat *indoors* instead of out -- and in that capacity, the newest ones are ridiculously more efficient than gas, and as such, cheaper to run than gas, particularly on less frigid days e.g. above 32F/0C.  (COP gets better as temperatures get higher).

But the new ones work all year - even in Chicago.  I'll cue up this video - but let me warn you - Alec's "failure condition" is efficiency falling below 2.5 COP for energy-security reasons (Alec did it days after Russia invaded Ukraine). It's still working quite well there - 2.5x as efficient as electric resistance heaters. And will continue to work (at lesser COP) into the coldest night in Alec's data.  Anyway [here's the video cued up](https://youtu.be/MFEHFsO-XSI?t=513).

And for the whole [heat pump series, here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI&list=PLv0jwu7G_DFVIot1ubOZdR-KC-LFdOVqi&index=3). I cued up video #3 assuming you scrolled back and watched the rest of video #2.  The first video covers the technology basics but is a little off on the state of the art.

Anyway if you dislike the mini-split format, they also make wall-unit heat pumps.  The hardware is the same as an air conditioner, they just add a $12 reversing valve and some software. The fact that they charge more than that is shameless (well, it's due to economies of scale).

### Modern heat pumps are also much more efficient.

And that means more cooling per watt when you're in A/C mode.  Federal Law says *the minimum* a legal SEER (coarsely, BTUs per watt) of 14 SEER for a pad-mounted outdoor unit. (or about 400% efficiency).  /not_impressed  Modern mini-splits go as high as 38 SEER.  That means half the electricity for the same cooling!

With the limited amount of power available at your home (make sure you are doing a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation), you must be careful about power usage.

> Local stores only stock 23,500 BTU units. They are double the price of the 12,500 BTU units but only pull 2 more amps.

*I seriously doubt that.  **That needs further explaining.*** Either one is 120V and the other is 240V (this matters!), or the SEER ratings are very different. If you're spending that kind of premium, I'd be looking closely at SEER and also at heat pumps.  I'm sorry they charge a premium for those, but they are worth it.

Not least, having gas heat *and* a heat pump insulates you against the varying costs of both - you can easily switch to the cheapest by adjusting your thermostat as to which it selects at what temperature.

### Watch your sun exposure when estimating BTUs

The "stock method" of getting BTUs from square feet **is dumb**.  It completely ignores the two most important factors in how much A/C you need:

- **Solar Gain** or how much direct sun is hitting your building. This is far-and-away the #1 source of heat which must be removed. Raw solar radiation is about 300 BTU per square foot. Insulation greatly slows this down - mainly by keeping the hot wall and roof on the outside where wind can cool it.  But there's no question that your house full-in-sun needs dramatically more cooling capacity than the exact same house in shade of trees.
- Quality of insulation is also a huge factor. Not only due to the skin losses due to differing air temperatures, but again that solar gain!  If solar gain is slashing right through your lack of insulation, you'll need more BTUs.

So at the very least, take their BTUs per square foot figures and greatly fudge-factor them based on conditions at your home.

### Don't sweat "too large a unit" / "short cycles"

Let's knock out "short cycling" right now.  The unit will have internal protection to prevent it.  (that is where the compressor restarts too soon after having shut down, and pressure has not yet equalized in the system, so it's making a hard start against pressure. Not even an issue for inverter-drive heat pumps).

But some people argue "if you get too many BTUs, the unit won't run long enough to dehumidify".  That's *not quite nonsense*, but is trivially managed *simply by running the unit longer*.  Say what?

"Run time" is about the *hysteresis* in the thermostat. Say you want 74F. Well you don't want to start the unit at 74.001°F and shut it down at 73.999°F! Then it would be on/off every 5 seconds and that would be ludicrous. (unless it's a heat pump with variable speed drive, cough cough).

So the thermostat has a reasonable "spread" in there. If you ask for 74F, it starts at 75F and shuts off at 73F.  Or whatever. Aside from giving the unit a reasonable *run time*, it also gives it a long enough *rest time* that short cycling won't be an issue.  The *rest time* is decided by solar gain and your house's insulation and thermal mass... the *run time* is decided by the BTU/hr of the unit x the thermostat's *hysteresis*.

So the simple answer to "too many BTUs, won't dehumidify because it's not running for long enough" is to increase the thermostat's hysteresis. Now it has a larger spread, for a longer runtime when it runs (and a longer rest time when it rests).  "That was easy!"

At extremes is [what our friend Alec does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0f9GpMWdvWI) to "game" the time-of-day utility rates. A $150 electric bill on a large all-electric house, *despite owning an electric car*.  In this case the A/C runs entirely at night, from 11pm until it's finished, and the house coasts through the entire day on stored cooling.  You don't need to be that extreme, but overcooling prior to 3 pm and then coasting through the critical peak grid hours may help your electricity bill.

Comment: Excellent write-up, as usual. Don't totally blow off unit size as a consideration though. A big temperature swing can be a different sort of uncomfortable in the right weather. It's really nice to have a unit that's properly sized.

Comment: I think you missed the "variable speed" aspect of good/efficient mini-splits - a 12,000 BTU/Hr rated unit may be able to run as low as 3,000 BTU/hr, which also changes the "oversizing consideration" .vs. fixed-speed units that are all or nothing. But still better to right-size, as that means more ability to run at the cooling/heating load without switching on and off, and that improves efficiency.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the problem with "right-sizing" is climate change.